# VB.Net - How to get GridView to only show Date from DateTime SQL column?

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have an SQL formula that I plan to use in an upcoming Web program developed in VB.NET, which will display the data obtained from my SQL formula in GridView.

There is a specific part of my SQL I'm having trouble with

```
select A.[Inv No], A.[Project No], 
cast([Record Date] as date)as [Date],   --This area is problem field
A.[Description], A.[Problem + Repair Details], 
A.[Status], convert(float, A.[Accumulative Stroke]) 
as [Accumulative Stroke],
convert(float, A.[Preventive Stroke]) 
as [Preventive Stroke], 
A.[PIC], A.[Measurement (OK/NG)] 
from [SQL].[dbo].[MAINT_ENTRY] A 

left join (select [Inv No], max(Date +' '+ Time) as [Record Date] 
from [SQL].[dbo].[MAINT_ENTRY] 
group by [Inv No]) B 

on A.[Inv No] = B.[Inv No]

where [Record Date] = Date +' '+ Time and 
[Problem + Repair Details] <> '""' 
Order by A.[Status], A.[Inv No], A.[Date]desc
```

`[Record Date]` is a column that merges the `Date` and `Time` column into a single merged column in order for me to get the very latest data to display in my program. Both of those fields need to be in `datetime` format in order for them to join.

I want the GridView to only show the Date in `Record Date` and since it is in `datetime` I tried using `CAST` to change the format as `date`.

Although it shows the correct result in SQL Management Studio, where I was simulating the results, it doesn't seem to want to play nice in VB.Net as the result I get still uses the `datetime` format. It deletes the time data but still keeps the time formatting.

```
22/4/2019 08:45:00 AM ---> 22/4/2019 12:00:00 AM
```

what seems to be the problem causing this?

Comment: The type you use in SQL doesn't really matter because .NET only has the `DateTime` type that contains both date and time. Even though VB has a `Date` type, that is just an alias for `DateTime`. If you don't want the time shown then you need to specify that in the formatting when you display the data in the UI. If you want to do that in a `GridView` control, the thing to do would be to research how to specify formatting in that control.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to cast the Datetime directly in the SQL query, in order to do that instead of

```
cast([Record Date] as date)as [Date]
```

you should do it like this:

```
CONVERT(varchar(10), [Record Date], 103) as [Date]
```

As the `CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )` syntax specifies: [Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: I have heard of this method before. However does the final result count as `varchar` format or `date` format? Because I was requested to specifically show it as a date.

Comment: "show it as a date"... from user perspective, it doesn't matter, does it? If it displays '22/04/2019', that's a date in my eyes ;) Anyways, if you want the result in "just date" format, take a look at @jmcilhinney 's comment, you should look up how to set Date format (without time) in a GridView control (RowDataBound event perhaps?) If you decide to do it that way, the sql query shouldn't have any cast/convert (so you don't repeat the same casting twice)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question, you are returning an object from some SQL server that has a DateTime field. You want to use VB to display just the date component.

In VB, there is a "Date" property to the DateTime object that you can use to display JUST the date component of the DateTime property.  A simple code example:

```
Dim myDateTime as DateTime = now()
MessageBox.Show("Today's date is: " + myDateTime.Date)
```

If you need more of a reference, have a look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netframework-4.8